# SplitButton title with glyphicon + text

Tags: reactjs, glyphicons, react-bootstrap

How can I make a title of a SplitButton with a glyphicon and tile just like classic button (crosshair).

Because when I try to do same as classic button with `<Glyphicon glyph="screenshot" /> Crosshair` it doesn't work so I tried `{<Glyphicon glyph="retweet"/>}'ROI'` or `{<Glyphicon glyph="retweet"/>}+'ROI' or <Glyphicon glyph="retweet"/>+'ROI'`

Nothing work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Put it inside your button tag like this:

```
<button><Glyphicon glyph="retweet"/> ROI</button>
```